# connecting to remote oracle via cygwin sqlplus

Tags: oracle, cygwin, sqlplus

I'm trying to use cygwin sqlplus to connect to a remote oracle installation located at myserver.mycompany.com port 1530.  When I try

```
sqlplus username@myserver.mycompany.com:1530/orcl
```

I get the error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

When I set `ORACLE_HOME` to /`cygdrive/c/oracle/product/10.2.0/client_1`, I get a different error:

```
Error 6 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory
```

I can telnet to the server's port 1530, and the SQL Developer installed locally is also able to connect to the database.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wasn't aware there was a native cygwin client for Oracle (correct me if I'm wrong here but I can't find any mention of it on Oracle's web site either).  If you're using Cygwin with the Windows client you need to use a native windows path.  It won't understand your /cygdrive path.

However, I have used Win32 Oracle clients with cygwin and made it work - the same shell scripts would work on Cygwin, Linux and Solaris.

Comment: Not directly related to the question, but the `cygpath` utility can be handy for converting back and forth between Windows and POSIX paths.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a cygwin Oracle client. As above answer, use the ORACLE_HOME set to the windows path.

For the first half of your question, try seeing what the TNS_NAMES env variable is set to, and if not set, you may need to try setting it to the correct place. Usually it defaults to %ORACLE_HOME%/network/admin/tnsnames.ora . SQL Developer keeps it's own copy of the tnsnames file, so you can't reply upon that to fix the problem.

Comment: It's TNS_ADMIN environment variable, not TNS_NAMES.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Combining the details from the other answers (which took me a little, so I post it as separate answer instead of comments):</sup>

The `$ORACLE_SID` and, if set, `$TNS_ADMIN` (and probably other path-related ***Oracle*** variables) must use Windows-paths. Your Cygwin `$PATH` variable should of course use the Cygwin notation (`/drives/c/…`). So I've included into my `.bashrc`:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=c:\\Oracle\\product\\12.1.0\\dbhome_1
export TNS_ADMIN=d:\\Oracle\TNSAdmin
export PATH=$PATH:$(cygpath -u $ORACLE_HOME)/BIN
```

After that, I had no more issues calling e.g. `tnsping` or `sqlplus`. As the above is just an example, you must of course adjust the paths to reflect your installation/configuration :)

Answer (score 0):

NXC is right - it wasn't a cygwin client I was using, but the windows sqlplus client.
I set the windows environment variables for `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` and was then able to run sqlplus in a cygwin bash shell using the `net_service_name` from tnsnames.ora.

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me was to remove `/cygdrive/d` or `/cygdrive/c` and replace them with with `d:/` or `c:/` and then your `sqlplus` call within cygwin session will work. The `/cygdrive/DriveLetter` is confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

I have same error like you,

you should set not only `ORACLE_HOME` in windows Variables,

But also `PATH` include `%ORACLE_HOME%\bin`

then you can open windows cmd,

try `sqlplus username/password@your_define_tnsname`

if okay, then remove all `ORACLE PATH` setting in cygwin, restart cygwin,try it.

if failure, should let sqlplus works well in windows cmd at first

Answer (score 0):

I have  TNS_ADMIN variable configured and it works properly in Win Environ
I used cygpath mnodification in .bashrc
If TNS_ADMIN is configured add following row to .bashrc

```
export TNS_ADMIN=$(cygpath -m $TNS_ADMIN)
```

Comment: Hmmmm, I can't get this to work but at leaset I discovered `cygpath`. Thank you :)